# remote desktop connection can't click on more of local resource

Tags: remote-desktop

I am having an issue with my computer windows 7 , In remote desktop connection when I try to click (more) button to check (C drive) or (D drive) it doesn't open,

I tried disabling anti-virus but it didn't work, is there any solution rather than formatting my computer.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78BGJ.png)

Comment: Similar problem in Windows 10: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX272255/more-button-in-remote-desktop-connection-mstscexe-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

Try to update yor RDP from Microsoft site from the below link:

[Update for Remote Desktop](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2592687/remote-desktop-protocol-rdp-8-0-update-for-windows-7-and-windows-serve?wa=wsignin1.0%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0)